# One wifi network isn't showing up

Tags: networking, wireless

I have two WiFi networks at home and one of them (the closer one) isn't showing up anywhere. I tried "connect to hidden network" option, but it didn't help. Could somebody help me with this? Right now I have my phone or tablet connected to my laptop via USB and I tether WiFi by it. It's also good to mention that even my school network works fine. It's only this one network, where I have trouble. I have [Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 adapter](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/qca9377) and I tried to reinstall its drivers in my Ubuntu 19.10 OS. [Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ3l5.png) of iw reg get; dmesg | grep ath commands.

Comment: Do you know what channel the problem wifi network is on?

Comment: It's on channel 13

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `iw reg get; dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: I included screenshot of results from terminal